# JQuery glyphicon - adding color

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap3 glyphicons. e.g.

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" title="Edit"></i>
```

I want it to be green so I use a class called public which is:

```
.public {
    color:green;
}
```

When I apply this to the icon it does not work. It stays gray.

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog public" title="Edit"></i>
```

Yet if I apply the style inline it works:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="color:green" title="Edit"></i>
```

Why is that?

Comment: it is working fine http://www.bootply.com/92829

Comment: there's obviously more going on than listed here... conflicting css see below

Comment: @Manish Thanks for the heads up about bootply, not come across that before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my best guess is there is an existing style more specific than your .public selector

try this:

```
.public {
    color:green !important;
}
```

to override the existing style - and give a google about css specificity - [ill grab a link in a second for you](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

check out that article for how css determines 'importance' of which styles it should apply ^ ^ ^

Comment: Not used !important much so thanks for the reminder, did the trick!

Comment: no problem but - i would strongly suggest avoid the use of important. i listed it here with the article to prove a point and show the source of your issue. it would be best for you to read through that and figure out exactly which selector is taking precedence so you can re-work your css to not require the `!important` as its not best practice,  edit: aye - good man!

Comment: I totally agree and am looking further into why not working but for now it's a band-aid